# Conexão com hibernate, erro java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate

Conexão com hibernate

Tenho uma aplicação onde realizei todas as configurações necessárias para roda o projeto seguindo o manual da empresa, acontece que estou tento um erro na abertura do mesmo relacionado a conexão com o banco.

o meu banco local tem os dados:

nome: localhost\SQLEXPRESS

login: sa

senha: root

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olá, no hibernate.connection.url deixe no seguinte formato:
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/fusion
Quando o drive JTDS é utilizado a sintaxe correta é utilizar o :jtds após o jdbc.